# Is it possible to disable/prevent automatic Task Creation for EmailMessages when Enhanced Email is enabled?

Tags: email, tasks

Org has enhanced email enabled, and customer is using a 3rd party product (Riva) to sync emails from Outlook to Salesforce (which creates EmailMessages).  Salesforce is automatically creating a Task for each EmailMessage.  Is there any way to prevent or disable this behavior?

We're considering a trigger to remove the tasks, but would prefer to never create them if possible.

Comment: I believe not. If you check the data model. `TaskId` is one of the lookup field on the `EmailMessage` object. The `Task` gets created first then the `EmailMessage`.

Comment: No `TaskId`, but there is an `ActivityId` on `EmailMessage` which does identify the created Task. However, I'm pretty sure that Riva is directly inserting `EmailMessage`s via API, so I'm expecting the Task to be created after, and the EmailMessage to be updated.  I intend to do some quick checking with some log-only triggers to confirm, prior to designing a trigger to remove the tasks.  Still hoping for a declarative way to turn off the Tasks though,

Comment: @JasonClark, we are facing the same issue. Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @Sem I don't think so.  This was nearly 4 years and 1 employer ago, so I no longer have access to the client's codebase.  IIRC, we ended up with a trigger to remove the tasks.

Comment: Ok thanks for your response @JasonClark